# Can't assign permission set to my user after installing Salesforce Data Mask!

Tags: managed-package, data, permission-sets, package-install, salesforce-data-mask

After installing the Salesforce Data Mask managed package in my org I get the following error when trying to assign the permission set to my user:

> Can't assign permission set Data Mask to user Renato Oliveira. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Custom Permission DataMaskAccess is not valid for this Permission Set.

But the permission set doesn't specify a license type, and I'm doing this as the System Administrator (Salesforce license).

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was not really clear from the [announcement](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2019/11/data-mask-secure-sandbox.html) or from most of the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_mask_overview.htm&type=5), but Salesforce Data Mask is actually a paid feature, and if you want to use it you need to talk to your Account Execute to purchase licenses.

As per the [documentation on installing Salesforce Data Mask](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=data_mask_install.htm):

> Ensure that your organization has the Data Mask User permission set licenses. Contact your Salesforce account executive to purchase more licenses.

Comment: Ok what if you need use it in a developer box or Trailhead Playground ? E.g. to complete a superbadge set

Comment: For a development scenario, you would use a scratch org instead. On creation you can add the "DataMaskUser" feature to get the permission set licenses added on org creation. In a Trailhead Playground I'm sure Salesforce would provide a way for you to have the licenses added to the environment too. Either automatically, or through a case.